# Speed up to invert an element (int type) in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I have a vector that size is `1 by 500` that its type `integer`. Given a invertible probability is P. For each element in the `vector`, I will create a random number, if the random number is smaller than P, then the element is inverted. For example, I have

```
vec=    [1   0   0   1   0   1]
random= [0.1 0.6 0.8 0.2 0.1 0.2]
P=0.5;
vec_new=[0   0   0   0   1   0]
```

*`For first element vec[0]=1 and random[0]=0.1<P=0.5 then vec_new[0]=invert of vec[0]=0, and so on`*
I implemented it, however, I think my code is not so fast, could you see and give me how to speed up the invert part in `C++`? Currently, I used

```
vec_new[k]=vec[k]+1)%2;//Invert
```

This is my code

```
//Assume vec=[1 0 0 1 0 1]
vector<int>  vec_new;
for(int i=0;i<vec.size();i++)
if(ranom_number<P)//random_number is within 0 to 1
    vec[i]=(vec[i]+1)%2;//Invert vec;
}
```

Comment: Why do you use `vector<int>` when you are dealing with only 2 different values (0 and 1)?

Comment: It is requirement of input data. It is int vec

Comment: `vec[i] = (ranom_number<P) ? !vec[i] : vec[i]`. Consider using an iterator instead of an index (that might be more micro-optimization that anything else).

Comment: `vec[i] ^= random_number < P;` ? Avoids branching. When P is small (e.g. under 0.1 - could determine exact cutoff experimentally), it should be much faster to randomly pick the elements to toggle (simplest to use P*500, but for equivalent behaviour you'd want some spread around that).

Comment: in my case, P may be very small 0.01 and size of vector is 100. Do you know any tool to check time consuming in my code? I am using visual studio 2012. I would like to check best solution

Comment: *I think my code is not so fast* -- why do you *think* it is not fast? How are you measuring time? You might just be concerned about the wrong things...

Comment: I think so, when I see it did not achieve my expected time

Comment: @user8430: A P of 0.01 / vector size 100 means only toggling 1 value on average - certainly don't want to do an iteration over all 100 elements if speed's of concern. Re how to profile code in VS - it's a separate question - best not to mix it in here, and I'm sure there are lots of existing answer available.  (this commented deleted/reposted to correct typo in value of P)

Answer (score 1):

> could you see and give me how to speed up the invert part in C++?

Consider:

```
vec[i] = !static_cast<bool>(vec[i]);
```

If you only have two possible values though (0 and 1) you may wish to work with bool dirrectly.

Comment: Yes, I have only 1 or 0. And the above solution convert int to bool type. After converting, it returns bool or int type, sir?

Comment: After converting it returns a bool, which is automatically converted to 1 as an int value and assigned to vec[i]

Comment: Thanks. Do you know any tool to check time consuming in my code? I am using visual studio 2012. I would like to check best solution

Answer (score 0):

Inversion can be expressed as a single operation `v[i] = 1 - v[i]`. I don't think that's the bottleneck. The vector is small (<4KB) and the RNG may very well be the slowest part of the loop.

Also, I'd be surprised if this part of the program is a bottleneck. Getting 500 random numbers may be the slowest part of the loop, but that's relative - it's still very fast.

The one thing that's probably suboptimal is the use of floating point numbers. Don't generate a number between 0.0 and 1.0. Generate an integer between 0 and N, and check if it's smaller than N*P.